# Hashing password using crypt does not work on the login it displays incorrect pass

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I have a register page that allow user to insert password so i need to hash it to become more secure in the database  this work fine

but when it come to the login the entered password do not match the register one how to fix this problemmm

this is my first time to use hash so it did not work as i want

**This is the register code for hash:**

```
   //ADD MD5 hash to the password 
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$test$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass1);      
echo $hashedpass;
```

the hashing password = $2y$09$test$5I9x8HWhA4UHi5TMu.AxfdWvZadDCE.LD6HCkrK3ZsqJeN7e

**This is the login code for hash:**

```
   function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$test$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass);   
echo $hashedpass;
```

the hashing password = $2y$09$test$4ZGgCiXdKzgQvuzwu.AxfdWvZadDCE.LD6HCkrK3ZsqJeN7e

Comment: Store the salt you generate for each user in the database, and retrieve that instead of making a new one.

Comment: anyone can help me???? i realy need it to work

Comment: You got several answers, even correct ones. You just need to understand and apply them.

Comment: the problem is that when it come to upply them it do not work as it should  anw thank you for your helping i did change the way of hashing and still having problem if you want to help me [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633972/hahing-password-in-register-and-login-do-not-match]

Answer (score 1):

Upon registration you create a unique salt. That salt is now part of the hash. If you look closely, you'll see it's embedded in the first part of the hash. To check the password, use the previous hashed password's salt, so you're using the same salt again.

```
$correctPasswordHash = getPasswordFromDatabase($_POST['username']);
$hash = crypt($_POST['password'], $correctPasswordHash);

if ($correctPasswordHash === $hash) ...
```

To make this easier and more foolproof, use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/), which wraps this in an easy to use API, which will also be integrated into a future version of PHP. Inspect its source code for the correct usage of `crypt`, since there are some pitfalls you need to take care of. The password_compat library is also using a custom binary comparison instead of a simple `===` to thwart timing attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, the login-time code is generating a fresh salt, ignoring the one that's stored with the password. Using different salts to hash the same password will generate different hashes.

Either use a <strike>constant salt</strike> [pepper (scroll to the bottom of this answer)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846), as per @c2's answer:

```
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
  return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$mysalt$', $rounds));
}
$hash = cryptPass($pass);
```

Or use the same salt both times:

```
// Login time (register-time code is unchanged)
function cryptPass($input, $salt, $rounds = 9)
{
  return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$%s$', $rounds, $salt));
}
function checkPass($freshPass, $hashFromDatabase) {
  $salt = explode('$', $hashfromDatabase, 5);
  $salt = $salt[3];
  return cryptPass($freshPass, $salt) === $hashFromDatabase;
}
```

Comment: so if i understand you correct in the query of the login password = '$hashFromDatabase'??

Comment: i need an example on my code because i do not know how to write  the function in the login to get the identacal pass sorry for the questions but its the first time for me that i use hashing