# Hashing password in register and login do not match

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, bcrypt

I've a register form that allow user to enter password and I hash this password using crypt

In the register form it work and the password is hashed and secure in the database but when it come to the login the password do not match and the system do not log in

Anyone can help me ???

## hashing password in register.php

```
//crypt password
      require_once('include/blowfish.php'); 

      $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
      $hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass1);
      echo $hash;


//************Insert all the members's input to the database**************************//
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(user_name, first_name, last_name, 
governorate, district, village, birth_date, email_address, specialization,
password, registered_date )

VALUES('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$governorate', '$district', 
'$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$hash', now())")

or die(mysql_error());
```

## hashing password in the login.php

```
$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name, user_name 
FROM members 
WHERE email_address='$email'AND password= '$pass' 
LIMIT 1") or die("error in members table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)
  {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
      $row_pass = $row['password'];
      //***********for hashing password***************************//
require_once('include/blowfish.php');
 $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
 if($bcrypt->verify($pass, $row_pass))
  {

          $id = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

          $firstname = $row['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

          $email = $row['email_address'];
          $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

          $username = $row['user_name'];
          $_SESSION['user_name']= $username;


          mysql_query("UPDATE members SET last_log_date=now() 
WHERE user_id='$id'");

        //$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
          header("Location: profile.php");
         // exit();   
  }//close if 
 }//close if 
  else
  {
      $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
      //exit();
  }
```

Comment: Don’t ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: You already got answers, try to understand and apply them!

Comment: @ deceze the problem is that i think it is right but it not and i do not know how to fix so that i come and ask question to get hel and understand

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in the 1-st snippet you save $hash into the members.password.

While in the second snippet you check for the real password from the input. You need to modify it to hash first:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
$hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass);

$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name, user_name 
FROM members
WHERE email_address='%s'AND password= '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
        mysql_real_escape_string(hash));

$sql=mysql_query( $query) or die("error in members table");

$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($login_check > 0)
{
    ...
```

Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and uses deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: so the code become like this : **require_once('include/blowfish.php');
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
$hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass);
$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name, user_name FROM members WHERE email_address='%s'AND password= '%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($email),
mysql_real_escape_string($hash));$sql=mysql_query( $query) or die("error in members table");$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($login_check>0){$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row_pass = $row['password'];
if($bcrypt->verify($hash, $row['password'])){**

Comment: but this produce another hash  not the same one